# Removing time from datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm currently trying to remove the `time` from a `datetime`.

These are the rows in the table

```
PK_Date
-----------------------
2011-07-03 00:00:00.000
2011-07-04 00:00:00.000
```

My code below works, but doesn't actually work. Meaning it doesn't give me an error, but when I look at the results, its still exactly the same. I want to change every single row in that table to become just date eg. 2011-03-04

Any Ideas? Cheers,

```
 UPDATE dbo.Time 
 SET PK_Date = CONVERT(date,PK_Date,111)  
 FROM dbo.Time
```

Comment: you do realize that a column is either a DATE or a DATETIME column, right? Setting a column defined as DATETIME to just a date will add the 00:00:00.000 timestamp. What's your table structure? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: A DateTime object is just a 'thing' that holds date and time information.  Its how you display it that matters.  If you dont want the time portion, then just dont display it in your application.

Comment: I need to create a time dimension and link to my fact table, PK_Date is the primary key for the time dimension, with the results from 2011-07-03 00:00:00.000 straight to 2013.
I need to create a cube using SSIS which wants me to show results based on place, monthly

Comment: I think what @RobP is trying to say is, if you have >= sql server 2008, you can change your column to a `DATE` type.  No time involved there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just want store date part try altering that column data type and make it as just date

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Time ALTER COLUMN PK_Date Date
```

Answer (score 1):

If your column datatype is `DATETIME`, you'll always have a time component to the value.  If you just want to see the date only, you can either `CONVERT` it to a string and style it, or `CAST` or `CONVERT` it to a `DATE`

```
SELECT CAST(PK_Date AS DATE) from dbo.Time
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, PK_Date) from dbo.Time
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), PK_Date, 111) from dbo.Time
```